# JIRA query to check if a parent issue has specific sub-tasks

Tags: jira, jql

We have a requirement to audit our JIRA's to ensure that each JIRA has specific subtasks.

We need to make sure that JIRA's have the exactly the following structure:

Parent
-subtask type 1
-subtask type 2
-subtask type 3

I've tried to use the [CraftForge](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugins/org.craftforge.jira.craftforge-jql-functions-plugin) plugin but I'm not sure exactly how to make the query work.  I guess I need something like:

```
issue in parentIssuesFromQuery(
  issuetype in subTaskIssueTypes() 
  and (
     issuetype = 'subtask type 1' and 
     issuetype = 'subtask type 2' and
     issuetype = 'subtask type 3'
   )
)
```

but clearly that won't return any results.  Any idea how this could be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I worked it out.  I needed to do several queries:

```
 not (
   (issue in parentIssuesFromQuery("issuetype in subTaskIssueTypes() AND 
      issuetype = 'subtask type 1'")) and 
   (issue in parentIssuesFromQuery("issuetype in subTaskIssueTypes() AND 
      issuetype = 'subtask type 2'")) and 
   (issue in parentIssuesFromQuery("issuetype in subTaskIssueTypes() AND 
      issuetype = 'subtask type 3'"))
 )
```

This is very slow though it works.  Would be grateful for any advice on how to do this more efficiently.

Comment: For others coming upon this 7+ years later, I experienced the same slowness with a similar function, havingSubtaskIssuesFromQuery("status != closed"), and was able to resolve by narrowing the query to "sprint in openSprints() and status != closed"). So... if for your use case you can narrow the search, that may speed things up.